# How to create an alias for a filtered column in a SQL query

Tags: sql

The SQL query below is giving me the desired results, but the use of CASE statements seems incorrect. 
Is there another way to create an alias for a filtered column? Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same results?

Here is the current query:

```
SELECT 
      year, 
      college_name, 
      count(id_999999999) as count_id_999999999,
      count(id_999999999)/count(student_id) as percent_id_999999999,
      count(id_other) as count_id_other,
      count(id_other)/count(student_id) as percent_id_other,
      count(student_id) as total_id

FROM      (SELECT fiscal_year, semester, 

                 CASE
                     WHEN student_id IN ('999999999') THEN 'id - 999999999' 
                 END
                 AS id_999999999,

                 CASE
                     WHEN student_id NOT IN ('999999999') THEN 'id - Other'
                 END
                 AS id_other,

                student_id

            FROM enrolment_data) enrol

GROUP BY    year, college_name
ORDER BY    year, college_name;
```

And here are the desired results:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is overly complicated.  You don't need a subquery.  I would write the query as:

```
SELECT year, college_name, 
       sum(case when student_id IN ('999999999') then 1 else 0 end) as count_id_999999999,
       avg(case when student_id IN ('999999999') then 1.0 else 0 end) as percent_id_999999999,
       sum(case when student_id NOT IN ('999999999') then 1 else 0 end) as count_id_other,
       avg(case when student_id NOT IN ('999999999') then 1.0 else 0 end) as percent_id_other
       count(*) as total_id
FROM  enrolment_data ed
GROUP BY year, college_name
ORDER BY year, college_name;
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why the AVG function is working here? That seems counter-intuitive, since the column does not display an average value.

Comment: @mariita . . . It actually is an average value.  When matches are 1 and non-matches are 0, then the average is the proportion of 1s.

Comment: But I want to know the percentage in relation to the  total number of records, including those with null values. So if there are 100 records, of which 10 have a null value for student_id and 20 have a value of 999999, then the percentage_999999 should be 20%. Would the AVG function work?